# Strange flashing white dot and lag in java swing program

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception

I am currently making a snake game using java swing. It is working well, except for one problem. The snake travels on a grid. When that grid is 22X22 or larger, a random cell will flash white every frame. This cell is different each frame. Also, response from key inputs lags one frame. This also happens only when the grid is 22X22 or greater. With smaller grid sizes, the game runs fine. Every few frames, the program will throw the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: No such child: 226
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.getComponent(Container.java:350)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.rectangleIsObscured(JComponent.java:4426)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1072)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:865)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1884)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
```

Here is my code:

```
package net.nuxoll.sebastian.snake.launch;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import net.nuxoll.sebastian.snake.board.DeathException;
import net.nuxoll.sebastian.snake.board.SnakeBoardPanel;

public class SnakeFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2842717162345016024L;
    
    public static final Dimension LAYOUT_DIM = new Dimension(750, 790);
    private SnakeBoardPanel board;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SnakeFrame frame = new SnakeFrame();
        frame.runGame();
    }
    
    public SnakeFrame() {
        setSize(LAYOUT_DIM);
        setTitle("Snake");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        board = new SnakeBoardPanel();
        add(board);
        
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void runGame() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                board.nextFrame();
                repaint();
                setVisible(true);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DeathException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
package net.nuxoll.sebastian.snake.board;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

import net.nuxoll.sebastian.snake.launch.SnakeFrame;

public class SnakeBoardPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3223596216217161034L;

    private static final int ROWS = 22;
    private static final int COLS = 22;
    private static final double SQUARE_WIDTH = SnakeFrame.LAYOUT_DIM.getWidth() / COLS;
    private static final double SQUARE_HEIGHT = SnakeFrame.LAYOUT_DIM.getHeight() / ROWS;
    private static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color SNAKE_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
    private static final Color APPLE_COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final int RIGHT = 1;
    private static final int UP = 0;
    private static final int LEFT = 3;
    private static final int DOWN = 2;
    private static final int EMPTY = 0;
    private static final int IFW = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
    
    private Random rand = new Random();
    
    private int snakex, snakey;
    private int applex, appley;
    private int direction;
    private int length;
    
    private int[][] board;
    
    public SnakeBoardPanel() {
        //Initializing variables
        snakex = 0;
        snakey = 0;
        applex = rand.nextInt(ROWS);
        appley = rand.nextInt(COLS);
        direction = RIGHT;
        length = 2;
        board = new int[ROWS][COLS];
        for(int[] column : board) Arrays.fill(column, EMPTY);
        
        //Adding the snake and apple
        board[0][0] = length;
        board[applex][appley] = -1;
        
        //Binding keys
        getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), UP);
        getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), DOWN);
        getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), LEFT);
        getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), RIGHT);
        getActionMap().put(UP, new MoveAction(UP));
        getActionMap().put(DOWN, new MoveAction(DOWN));
        getActionMap().put(LEFT, new MoveAction(LEFT));
        getActionMap().put(RIGHT, new MoveAction(RIGHT));
        
        //Displaying the board
        setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS));
        displayBoard();
    }
    
    public void nextFrame() throws DeathException {
        nextBoard();
        removeAll();
        displayBoard();
    }
    
    private void nextBoard() throws DeathException {
        //Moving the snake head
        switch(direction) {
        case UP:
            --snakex;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            ++snakex;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            ++snakey;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            --snakey;
            break;
        }
        
        //Eating and replacing the apple
        if(snakex == applex && snakey == appley) {
            ++length;
            while(true) {
                applex = rand.nextInt(ROWS);
                appley = rand.nextInt(COLS);
                if(board[applex][appley] == EMPTY) {
                    board[applex][appley] = -1;
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }
        
        //Decaying the end of the snake
        else for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) for(int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j) if(board[i][j] > 0) --board[i][j];
        
        //Adding the head to the snake. If the head is out of bounds or in the body, game over.
        try {
            if(board[snakex][snakey] > EMPTY) throw new DeathException();
            board[snakex][snakey] = length;
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new DeathException();
        }
    }
    
    private void displayBoard() {
        for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j) {
                if(board[i][j] == EMPTY) add(new ColorSquare(SQUARE_HEIGHT, SQUARE_WIDTH, BACKGROUND_COLOR/*, board[i][j]*/));
                else if(board[i][j] > EMPTY) add(new ColorSquare(SQUARE_HEIGHT, SQUARE_WIDTH, SNAKE_COLOR/*, board[i][j]*/));
                else add(new ColorSquare(SQUARE_HEIGHT, SQUARE_WIDTH, APPLE_COLOR/*, board[i][j]*/));
            }
        }       
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
        int direction;
        
        MoveAction(int direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if(Math.abs(SnakeBoardPanel.this.direction - direction) % 2 == 1) SnakeBoardPanel.this.direction = direction;
        }
    }
}
```

```
package net.nuxoll.sebastian.snake.board;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class ColorSquare extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5098473113009138202L;
    
    private double height, width;
    //private int n;
    private Color color;
    
    public ColorSquare(double height, double width, Color color/*, int n*/) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.color = color;
        //this.n = n;
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(color);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height));
        //g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        //g2.drawString(String.valueOf(n), 20, 20);
    }
}
```

```
package net.nuxoll.sebastian.snake.board;

public class DeathException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7740285889636925843L;

    public DeathException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
    
    public DeathException() {
        super("You Died!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Start here and work through:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: I am confused as to why I need to use concurrency. Everything I'm doing happens one thing after another. There should be no reason that it needs to do two things at once.

Comment: Your `runGame()` method runs on the main thread, Swing does it's redrawing and event handling on the EDT, so you **already have** two threads. And the flickering comes from the fact that you call `removeAll()` within `SnakeBoardPanel.nextFrame()` from the main thread instead of the EDT.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: *"Thanks, .."* Thank who? Tip: Add @ThomasKläger (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.